# Python module to generate HTML objects (like Select/Option)

Tags: python, html, widget

I have seen there are Tkinter widgets to create Combo and List boxes, but is there one that can create a similar object to the HTML Select/Option:

```
<select id="vehicleTypes">
<option value="1">Cars</option>
<option value="2">Trains</option>
<option value="3">Human RealLife space vehicles</option>
<option value="4">SuperStarDestroyers from yet another galaxy</option>
</select>
```

You see one thing (option innerHTML) but another value (option value) is returned.  This doesn't seem possible in the documentation I have seen, you can pass a list/tuple/range only ("Cars", "Trains", "Human RealLife space vehicles", "SuperStarDestroyers from yet another galaxy").

The reason for this is that I have a (currently) JSON object/associative array  with RPG spell data loaded as a javascript .js variable/JSON file:

```
spells = <br>
[
 {associative array of data},
 {associative array of data},
 ....
 {2009 entries later}
]
```

A sorted list of all entries (sorted by level then name: 'Level : Name' is the displayed format) goes into an Option object (option.innerHTML) with the value of each Option being the index (option.value) (then appendChild'd to a select) of the data so that you can reference data as spells[index][key] once an option is selected and the index returned.

As a way to learn Python, I am wanting to translate a working HTML project of mine.  This looks to be my first/main hurdle at the moment (I solve problems in parts then bring it all....l together).